# My LinkedList doesn't show up corectly after sorting

Tags: java

I have created in my program my own LinkedList (not from java.util) of cards.

Each card is an object made of 2 ints - the first one is a value ("wartosc" in my code) of a card (from 1 to 13), second is a colour ("kolor" in my code) for a card (from 0 to 3).

The list is randomly generated and the list is created when a value is 0. 
Now I have to modify "add" method ("dodaj" in my code) to make it add cards in correct place in the list. Not sorting method adds cards and the rest works fine (all cards are shown) but when I use method that is supposed to add cards in order and when I then try to print list of cards it shows only like from 2 to 5 of them - all sorted except for the last one. But when I print the size of list ot shows numbers like 20 or even 40, even though I print only 4. So i would like to know what is wrong. Here is the code:

```
public class Lista {
private Element pocz; //start
public int rozmiar;

public Lista() {
    boolean zrobione = false;
    while (zrobione != true) {
        Karta karta = new Karta();
        if (karta.getWartosc() == 0) {
            zrobione = true;
        } else {
            this.dodaj(karta);
        }
    }
}
public void dodaj(Karta k){
    if(pocz == null)
        pocz = new Element(k);

    Element pom = new Element(k);
    Element obecny = pocz;
    boolean zrobione = false;
    if(obecny != null && !zrobione){
        while(obecny.getNext() !=null && (obecny.getNext().getKarta().wartosc > obecny.getKarta().wartosc || (obecny.getNext().getKarta().wartosc == obecny.getKarta().wartosc && obecny.getNext().getKarta().kolor > obecny.getKarta().kolor))){
            obecny = obecny.getNext();
        }
        obecny.setNext(pom);
        zrobione = true;
    }
    rozmiar++;
}

 //   public void dodaj(Karta k) {
 //       if (pocz == null) {
 //           pocz = new Element(k);
   //     }
//
  //      Element pom = new Element(k);
    //    Element obecny = pocz;
      //  if (obecny != null) {
    //        while (obecny.getNext() != null) {
    //            obecny = obecny.getNext();
    //        }
    //        obecny.setNext(pom);
    //    }
    //    rozmiar++;
  // }

public int getRozmiar(){
    return rozmiar;
}

public void drukujOKolorze(int kolor){
    if(kolor<0 || kolor>4)
        System.out.println("Bledny kolor");
    else{
        Element obecny = null;
        if(pocz != null){
            obecny = pocz.getNext();
            while(obecny.getNext() != null){
                if(obecny.getKarta().kolor == kolor)
                    System.out.println(obecny.getKarta().toString());
                obecny = obecny.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}
public void drukujOWartosci(int wartosc){
    if(wartosc<0 || wartosc>13)
        System.out.println("Bledna wartosc");
    else{
        Element obecny = null;
        if(pocz != null){
            obecny = pocz.getNext();
            while(obecny.getNext() != null){
                if(obecny.getKarta().wartosc == wartosc)
                    System.out.println(obecny.getKarta().toString());
                obecny = obecny.getNext();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void wyswietl(){
    if(pocz != null){
        Element obecny = pocz.getNext();
        while(obecny != null) {
            System.out.println(obecny.getKarta().toString());
            obecny = obecny.getNext();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Sorry for not using English names - I will put below a short dictionary :)

- Lista() is constructor of List it checks if generated value is 0, then uses "dodaj" method
- "dodaj" method is "add" the first one is supposed to sort cards
- second "dodaj" that i put i comment for now was the 1st one that just adds new 
  cards. They aren't sorted but next methods work as intended when I use this one.
- getRozmiar() returns size of List, "rozmiar" means "size"
- "drukujOKolorze" and "drukujOWartosci" are supposed to print respectively: 
  cards of given colour and cards of given value - they work fine.
- and finally "wyswietl" which is "print". When i use the second "dodaj" it prints all the cards that are in list. When I use the first "dodaj" it shows only like 2 to 5 cards and the last one is never sorted while "getSize()" shows that there is more cards in the list.

I hope You guys will help me. I have no idea what goes wrong here and no, I can't use compareTo. My task is to write method that will put cards in order.

Comment: Hint: putting up a [mcve] very much raises your chances of a good answer. You expect a lot from people to keep scrolling up and down to translate themselves, just because you are sorry, too lazy to do that for the people you intend to ask for help.

Comment: SO.com is an english speaking website, please use english names in your code if you want us to read it.

Answer (score 1):

When you find the place that you want to put your card, you are setting it as the next item in the linked list, but not re-attaching the rest of the list after the new entry, effectively removing all cards after the insertion point.

Imagine it as an actual chain of metal links.
You open one of the links in the middle, breaking the chain into two pieces, then add the new link to one side.  However, you are not attaching the other half of the chain to the new link, so it is lost.

Try this:

```
public void dodaj(Karta k){
    if(pocz == null)
        pocz = new Element(k);

    Element pom = new Element(k);
    Element obecny = pocz;
    boolean zrobione = false;
    if(obecny != null && !zrobione){
        while(obecny.getNext() !=null && (obecny.getNext().getKarta().wartosc > pom.getKarta().wartosc || (obecny.getNext().getKarta().wartosc == pom.getKarta().wartosc && obecny.getNext().getKarta().kolor > pom.getKarta().kolor))){ // Modified line
            obecny = obecny.getNext();
        }
        pom.setNext(obecny.getNext()); // Added line
        obecny.setNext(pom);
        zrobione = true;
    }
    rozmiar++;
}
```

Comment: It indeed works again but doesn't sort the cards at all now, just like second "dodaj" which is kinda strange

Comment: Oh, right.  That's because you are comparing each card in the list to the next card in the list, rather than comparing it to the card that you want to add.  Edited the example above.